# Bot Discord error "Cannot read property 'send' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to get the bot to send a private message when someone reacts in a message, but is giving the error "Cannot read property 'send' of undefined"

This is my code:

```
bot.on('raw', async dados => {
      if(dados.t !== "MESSAGE_REACTION_ADD") return
      if(dados.d.message_id != "775402467692642305") return

      let servidor = bot.guilds.cache.get("544551800930435096")
      let membro = servidor.members.cache.get(dados.d.user_id)

      let tts = dados.d.user_id

      try{
        
      if(dados.t === "MESSAGE_REACTION_ADD") {
        if(dados.d.emoji.name === ""){
          bot.membro.send("eae")
        }
        }
      }catch (e){
          console.log(e)
        }


    })
```

Comment: is `bot.membro.send` right? should not be `bot.send`?

Comment: membro, I put to get the user id

Comment: where did you set it?

Comment: let membro = servidor.members.cache.get(dados.d.user_id)

Comment: If `membro` is a member then you can just `.send()` and it will send that member a PM.

Comment: When I put `.send ()` it gives the error SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.' and when I put bot.send () it is not recognized as a function

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code here is that you're trying to send a DM to `bot.membro` which does not exist. Additionally, trying to use `bot.send()` will give you an error because you're trying to DM the bot application or even the bot User, both of which aren't possible. You can use `membro.send()`, assuming that `membro` is a User, which will DM them a message. Below is the code

```js
bot.on('raw', async dados => {
      if(dados.t !== "MESSAGE_REACTION_ADD") return
      if(dados.d.message_id != "775402467692642305") return

      let servidor = bot.guilds.cache.get("544551800930435096")
      let membro = servidor.members.cache.get(dados.d.user_id)

      let tts = dados.d.user_id

      try{
        
      if(dados.t === "MESSAGE_REACTION_ADD") {
        if(dados.d.emoji.name === ""){
          membro.send("eae") // Sends msg to the user 
        }
        }
      }catch (e){
          console.log(e)
        }


    })
```

Comment: You're welcome! Please click the check mark next to the votes to show others that this answer helped you